# Spring Boot: Basic Auth Returning 401 But Works in Postman

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to consume a secured API using basic auth, but I keep getting back 401 error. The issue is the credentials and requested URL connect successfully when using Postman. Here is the call I am making, not sure if there is anything I am missing:

```
public ResponseEntity randomSht(){

       String username = "APIKEY";
       String password = ":PASSWORD";
       HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
       headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);

       // request url
       String url = "https://test.myshopify.com/admin/orders/2013413015622.json";

       RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();


       HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

       ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
               url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);

        System.out.println(response);

       return response;
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe your password is just `PASSWORD`, you don't need to add the `:`, if this is just the devider between header name and value.